# How to distinguish a downloaded song vs a downloaded song from Apple Music on iOS 11?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, mpmediaitem

I checked this on iOS 10:

```
if item.assetURL == nil { // item as MPMediaItem
  // apple music song
} else {
  // download song
}
```

And it works, but on iOS 11 it doesn't.